# Is it possible to find a copy of the Cartan seminar (1954–1955) on homotopy and Eilenberg–Mac Lane spaces?

Tags: reference-request

I am trying to find a comprehensive reference on Cartan's construction, the comparison theorem of Moore and related subjects. I have the following references

- Cartan, H., Algebres d’Eilenberg-Mac Lane, Seminaire Cartan, ENS, 1954-55, expos´es 2 to 11.
  (128, 180, 194, 197, 224, 232, 468)
- Moore, J.C., Cartan’s constructions, the homology of $K(\pi,n)$’s, and some later developments,
  Colloque “Analyse et Topologie” en l’Honneur de Henri Cartan (Orsay, 1974), pp. 173–212.
  Asterisque, No. 32-33, Soc. Math. France, Paris, 1976. (194)

Does anybody know where one might obtain a copy of these, or know about other
references about the topics in those notes and articles?

Comment: The Cartan Seminar is at: http://www.numdam.org/actas/SHC

Comment: @FZaldivar Thank you! I would say that can be put as an answer. I think that I should be able to find Moore's article in the same webpage.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Cartan Seminar is at: http://www.numdam.org/actas/SHC

Actually most French journals and seminars have been digitized and can be fount at: http://www.numdam.org/

Unfortunately, Astérisque has not been digitized completely and is not in the list; perhaps the only ones that are digitized are the volumes corresponding to Bourbaki seminars published in Astérisque.